# Mongoid 5 support for two phased commit

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

MongoDB docs prodivde pretty good explanation https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/ but does Mongoid 5 support it?  Or provide any helpful wrappers?

Could not find any issues on https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MONGOID/ either.